# Adding url() breaks hook_mail implementation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm writing a module in Drupal-7 that dynamically sends a one-time login link to guests. Everything fires fine until I add the link to the `$message` array, when it chokes. If I do a `dpm($message)` the link appears in the `$message['body']` array, as I would expect. If I comment out the line with the `url()` function, everything works as it should. Why is php/Drupal choking on this silly little link?

```
/*
 * Implement hook_mail().
 */

function rsvp_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch($key) {
      case "send invite" :
        $timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;
        $account = $params['account'];
        $message['subject'] = "And invitation for $account->name";
        $message['body'][] = 'Some body text.';
        $message['body'][] = 'Some more text!';
        //here's the line that's breaking my brain:
        $message['body'][] = url( 'http://wedding.juicywatermelon.com/rsvp/' . $account->uid . "/" . $timestamp . "/" . md5($account->pass . $timestamp) . "/" . 'user/' . $account->uid . '/edit/Wedding');             
        break;
    }
  }
```

ps - I had the code to generate the link in a seperate function call and moved it to the hook implementation for brevity. This, however had no effect on the behaviour.

and the code that generates the email:

```
function rsvp_mail_send($account) {
  $module = 'rsvp';
  $from = "email@gmail.com";
  $key = "send invite";
  $params['account'] = $account;
  $to = $account->mail;
  $language = language_default();
  $send = TRUE;
  $result = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in Drupal's logs, or your system PHP logs? Do you have mail routing back to the logs using the Devel module (this is a good idea at this stage)? Checking on these things may shed more light on what is happening and exactly where the failure is occurring in the long chain of PHP functions involved.

Comment: Wierd! It really doesn't like the $account object (which passes fine - i can confirm with dpm()). I'm trying to use elements from the $account obj in the url I'm generating but the mail system won't accept this. :/ (I can also return the url fine via dpm())

Comment: I can pass the $account object to the url() function and it returns ok, and I can pass it to the $message object and send it along, but I can't pass the object to the url() and pass that to the $message object.

Comment: Have you tried being selective about which fields from the $account object to pass in? Try not passing in the password, just the uid, and see if you experience the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an extra argument to the url() function which is called options, it's an array and in this array use the key 'absolute' and set it to TRUE to indicate that the URI that you pass as a first argument is an absolute URL.

See the documentation page for more information:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/7

Comment: @artusamak: Noted. However adding the $options array doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @artusamak http://pastebin.com/wGDawZtL - if i remove line 26, this works beautifully... thanks for any help!

Comment: Generating the url may not be the issue, can you log the value returned just to test it? Use watchdog() for that. When this is done first try to hardcode the url to see if it's the format or the call to the function which is good. I think that you didn't answer to a previous question, do you have any error / warning error message displayed?

Comment: @artusamak - thanks for the help with this! No, there are no error messages generated in the php log or watchdog (or by devel). If I set $result = drupal_mail('rsvp', 'send_invite', $account->mail, language_default(), $params = array('account' => $account), $from = 'starsinmypockets@gmail.com', $send = TRUE); and then dpm($result;) $result['result'] => TRUE for each mail sent. I wonder if it has to do with the text encoding in the header? Again, changing the url to a simple string gets the email through... but nothing changes in the log, dpm etc... I'm gonna try the encoding.. thanks

Comment: Added line: $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes'; to no avail. Added watchdog entry which confirms that mail result=1 each time...

Comment: @artusamak the culprit: google spam box. The url and the mail is fine - google is simply filtering the result into the spam box. Thanks for the debugging tips.